# How to open a remote folder from command line in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can start VS Code to open a local folder using `code /path/to/folder`. Is it possible to open a folder on a remote machine (via the Remote SSH extension) by specifying the machine and folder on the command line?

Comment: you can't do that because it will be violated the security.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vscode (code.exe) command line arguments to immediately open a remote workspace folder over SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64710228/vscode-code-exe-command-line-arguments-to-immediately-open-a-remote-workspace)

Answer (score 17):

From the cli on linux or mac terminal:

`code --folder-uri=vscode-remote://ssh-remote+<HOSTNAME><ABSOLUTE_PATH>`

Something like:

`code --folder-uri=vscode-remote://ssh-remote+centos8stream.local/home/guillaume/workspace/`

---

In my `~/.ssh/config` file I have:

```
Host centos8stream.local
    Hostname 10.41.11.69
    User guillaume
```

In my terminal I can ssh to my server doing `ssh centos8stream.local`

Then I can open vscode on my remote server directly:

`code --folder-uri=vscode-remote://ssh-remote+centos8stream.local/home/guillaume/workspace/`

I even created an alias function in my `~/.zshrc` file

```
function rcode() { code --folder-uri=vscode-remote://ssh-remote+$1/home/guillaume/$2 }
```

Then I just type

`rcode centos8stream.local workspace/my_project`

Comment: A little bit cleaner version of the function is:
`function rcode() {code --remote ssh-remote+$1 $2}`

based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64710228/vscode-code-exe-command-line-arguments-to-immediately-open-a-remote-workspace

Answer (score 0):

Mount the remote folder in your dev box and open it in VSCode.