# Vscode (code.exe) command line arguments to immediately open a remote workspace folder over SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line, vscode-remote

If I want to open a workspace on a regular local folder under C:\ I can just execute the command:

```
code.exe C:\the-local-workspace-folder
```

Is there any equivalent command for opening remote SSH workspaces?

I want to be able to use my keyboard launcher to open them, rather than needing to open them the fiddly way in the internal menus inside vscode.

So I need a regular system command to be able to do this.

I've looked through the command line arguments here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line - but can't find anything about remote workspaces at all.

I've also tried commands like:

```
code.exe username@hostname.example.com:/workspace-folder
code.exe username@hostname.example.com/workspace-folder
```

...but they don't work for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like a recent fix, according to the [issue tracking here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/585#issuecomment-536580102). I've tested with my own settings, and this works:

```
"C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" \
    --remote ssh-remote+myubuntumachine /home/myusername/myprojectdirectory
```

The `myubuntumachine` should be the name given in the `Host myubuntumachine` in the SSH config file on `CTRL+SHIFT+P`/Remote SSH: Open Configuration File...

(Actually, on my machine I don't have the machine name, but some sort of hash value, although either works.)

Comment: This would be a nice add on to the `~/.zshrc`:
`function rcode() {code --remote ssh-remote+$1 $2}`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60144074/how-to-open-a-remote-folder-from-command-line-in-vs-code

Comment: Now documented here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_connect-to-a-remote-host-from-the-terminal

Comment: From the WSL2 terminal this didn't work for me and I had to use `code --folder-uri=vscode-remote://ssh-remote+<HOSTNAME><ABSOLUTE_PATH>` as instructed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60144074/how-to-open-a-remote-folder-from-command-line-in-vs-code

Answer (score 2):

VSCode 1.63 (Nov. 2021) adds the option `-n` ([issue 137529](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/137529)), to make sure a new window is opened for remote CLI:

> The following options got added to the remote CLI:
>
> `-n` to open a new window of the same remote as the current window
> `-n --remote=wsl+ubuntu` to open a new window of a different remote
> `-n --remote=local` to open a new local window

Answer (score 1):

To get started, you need to:

Install an [OpenSSH compatible SSH client](https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/download/extension) if one is not already present.

Install [Visual Studio Code](https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/download/extension) or [Visual Studio Code Insiders](https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/download/extension).

Install the [Remote Development extension pack](https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/download/extension).

Read more : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

Installations extension :

```
code.exe --install-extension ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh
```

[Follow the step-by-step tutorial](https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/ssh/tutorial) or if you have a simple SSH host setup, connect to it as follows:

> Press **F1** and run the **Remote-SSH: Open SSH Host...** command. Enter
> your user and host/IP in the following format in the input box that
> appears and press enter: **user@host-or-ip** or
> **user@domain@host-or-ip** If prompted, enter your password (but we suggest setting up key based authentication). After you are connected,
> use **File** > **Open Folder** to open a folder on the host.

You can press **F1** to bring up the Command Palette and type in **Remote-SSH** for a full list of available commands.
[command list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbJ6q.png)

You can change the location by launching VS Code with the **--extensions-dir**  command-line option.

Where are extensions installed?#
Extensions are installed in a per user extensions folder. Depending on your platform, the location is in the following folder:

> **Windows** %USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions
>
> **Linux** ~/.vscode/extensions
>
> **macOS** ~/.vscode/extensions

To run remote ssh and open the folder in command-line :

```
code.exe --remote ssh-remote+root@server.com <your-directory>
```

Comment: That's not what they are asking.

Comment: @KenY-N Check it